# What does the java thread's state really mean?

Tags: java, android, performance, thread-dump, thread-state

I am learning the tool in Android Studio, get thread dump, as follow:

[image: get thread dump]

I notice the different state of every thread like this,

[image]

I can see there are `runnable`,`sleeping`,`waiting`. And I deep into the thread stack, most thread stack like this,

```
"<61> RxComputationScheduler-3@830064517520" daemon prio=5 waiting
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
        at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1050)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:778)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am confused that they do all halt at `Object.wait`, however the state of thread can be `runnable`,`sleeping`,`waiting`?

Here is the other state thread's stack.

`RUNNABLE`

```
<53> RxSchedulerPurge-1@830057651944" daemon prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2056)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:778)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)</code>
```

`TIMED_WAITING`

```
<58> RxScheduledExecutorPool-2@830064740632" daemon prio=5 sleeping
  java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2056)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:778)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Please use `code` instead of images for the stack trace.

Comment: Please start accepting answers. I'm not talking about this question in particular, I'm talking about all your questions where you have good but unaccepted answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**New** means the thread is in new state if you create an instance of `Thread` class but before the invocation of `start()` method:

```
Thread t = new Thread(...); // t is New
```

**Runnable** means the thread is in runnable state after invocation of `start()` method. Basically:

```
t.start(); // t is Runnable
```

**Running** is the "sub-state" of **Runnable**: the thread is in running state if the thread scheduler has selected it. You can't do anything with it explicitly, meaning you call `start()` and then just wait.

**Ready** is another "sub-state" of **Runnable**: the thread is eligible for running and waits for the thread scheduler to select it.

**Blocked** means the state when the thread is still alive, but is currently not eligible to run. This happens, for example, when one thread comes across a `synchronized` block, which is processed by another thread. In this case the first thread becomes **blocked**.

**Waiting** is the state when your thread is neither **blocked** nor **ready**. This usually happens when you call `wait()` or `join()` on a thread.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(); // t1 is New
Thread t2 = new Thread(); // t2 is New
t1.start(); // t1 becomes Runnable
t2.start(); // t2 becomes Runnable
t1.join(); // t2 becomes Waiting, because t1 is processed until it terminates
```

There is also a state called **Timed Waiting**, which is almost the same thing, but is caused by calling `sleep()`. If you call `wait(timeout)` or `join(timeout)`, the thread also gets **timed waiting** state.

```
Thread t = new Thread(); // t is New
t.start(); // t is Runnable
t.sleep(4000); // t get state of Timed Waiting for 4 seconds
```

**Terminated** is a thread in terminated or dead state when it's `run()` method exits.

I think I covered it all :) Here is an image to help you understand it more clearly:

[image: Thread Life Cycle Java]

As JoxTraex requested, here're sources I read before posting:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html
2. javarush.ru
3. http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/java-6-thread-state-machine-diagram-example.html
4. http://www.journaldev.com/1044/thread-life-cycle-in-java-thread-states-in-java

It's just a matter of good googling skill, really...

Comment: Could you please post your source and where you ate getting this info from?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static enum Thread.State
extends Enum<Thread.State>
```

A thread state. A thread can be in one of the following states:

```
NEW
A thread that has not yet started is in this state.

RUNNABLE
A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.

BLOCKED
A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.

WAITING
A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.

TIMED_WAITING
A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.

TERMINATED
A thread that has exited is in this state.
```

A thread can be in only one state at a given point in time. These states are virtual machine states which do not reflect any operating system thread states.

refer [oracle's api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) for more information.